# Load CSS for each browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I hope you can help me.
I need to load a css for each browser, (chorme, safari, mozilla, ie).
I have found a solution to which I add the safari option, but still it does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var browser = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1 ? 'chrome' : 'other';
    if (BrowserDetect.browser.indexOf("chrome")>-1) {
document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/chrome.css" />');
} else if (BrowserDetect.browser.indexOf("mozilla")>-1) {
    document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mozilla.css" />');
} else if (BrowserDetect.browser.indexOf("explorer")>-1) {
    document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" href="css/explorer.css" />');
} else if (BrowserDetect.browser.indexOf("safari")>-1) {
    document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" href="css/safari.css" />');
}
</script>
```

on the page there is an HTML5 audio player, in each browser this player changes color, so they must be different for each one.

Comment: Do you mean that it works with all browsers except Safari?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on Modernizr and Conditionizr.

Reasons:

1. They are good Javascript libraries
2. You don't re-invent the wheel. DRY principle
3. They get updated, they adapt to all major browser changes so you don't have to keep track of the evolution of all browsers

http://conditionizr.com/

https://modernizr.com/

I know this is not an exact answer and I can be downvoted, but I think is the best way to go. Which can works today for a Safari version, tomorrow can fail.

For conditionizr you have an example just for your case in

```
https://github.com/conditionizr/conditionizr/blob/master/docs/DOCS.md#basic-config-setup
```

Comment: That's the best way to go!